# Use NID in contextual filter on front page

Tags: blocks, views

I have a view set up that creates a block with some fields from a node. It uses the NID as a contextual filter so that the block shows the correct node's fields. This works fine on the individual node pages.

However, the latest node is shown on the front page (via another view). The blocks are not pulling the NID on the front page and therefore the blocks are not appearing.

Is there a way to pass the NID that is loaded via the front page view to the contextual filter so that the block appears?